# Unity3D Bug Visual Layer Matrix

Tags: unity-game-engine

MY Layer matrix 3d is bugged, it does not let me see or edit these values ​​comfortably. I have already tried to solve it temporarily by modifying the UI code using UI Toolkit but when updating the interface it looks bugged again

[2D layer (as good)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQrkB.png)

[3D layer mask BUGGED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujXw5.png)

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: it doesnt look bugged it looks like you unselected (or by code unselected) a lot of things

Comment: He means the labels are not alligned vertically with the checkboxes so at a point he might be unsure what he is enabling/disabling unless he counts. It took me some minutes to figure it out too, because the way he worded it all is so vague, but that seems to be his issue. Looks like some pixel scaling problem or something similar.